# Compare 2 Lists of E-mail Addresses

Tags: comparison, data-validation

How can I go about performing a comparison between 2 lists of e-mail addresses? Specifically, I am looking to find what e-mail addresses are not present in one list vs the other.

Comment: What tools do you have available? What have you tried? I know this kind of lookup is possible via various spreadsheets but don't know all of the various tools and their options.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://text-compare.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

- [I prefer WinMerge](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/winmerge_portable) since I am most familiar with GUI tools
- However I see you're a SW developer so maybe you'll like [PowerShell `compare-object (get-content one.txt) (get-content two.txt)`](https://serverfault.com/questions/5598/how-do-i-diff-two-text-files-in-windows-powershell) (*might be able to simplify to `diff (gc one.text) (gc two.txt)`*). You never

You never specified if you had searched, tried anything, or if you'd like your solution to be compatible with certain Operating System or environment.

Answer (score 2):

Using Excel will work

Put email list 1 into A column
Put email list 2 into B column

use the formula
=MATCH(B1,A:A,0)

Result will be either #N/A for no match or it will give a number, which is the row number in list 1 where the first occurrence of the email occurs.